Current flow through a busbar

In a circuit with a battery, charger and fridge connected via busbars, where does the fridge draw current from?
If the charger is producing 5A and the fridge is drawing 10A, does the fridge draw 5A from each source, or does the fridge draw 10A from the battery and the charger supplies 5A to the battery at the same time?

We can't guess how current flows in your circuit. Also there is either current going in or current coming out of battery, it does not charge and discharge simultaneously. Please draw a schematic and maybe there is an answer.

Thanks for the response. If the fridge is drawing 10A and the charger is supplying 5A,  does the fridge draw 5A from the charger and 5A from the battery?

If your circuit is ideal, and you know that 10A goes to load, and 5A comes from one supply, according to Kirchhoff's law for currents, there must be 5A coming from another supply, i.e. the batteries.
In real life, although the currents have to sum up, the wiring has some resistance, as well as the supplies and batteries, so what the actual currents are depends on these non-idealities.

Ok, I think I get it. So, with resistance aside, if the current from the charger is variable (like with solar), the fridge will draw what it can from the charger and the balance from the battery. Then assuming the charger produces more than the fridge requires, the battery would draw the excess (assuming it's not at capacity). Thank you!
